# Where to find the next_page_token in a Google Maps Nearby Search (new) response?

Tags: rest, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using the "(New)" Places API through the REST endpoints and am trying to give my users the option to load a second page of place results. I know that you were able to do this in the old Places API by accessing a next_page_token in the response and sending another request, but this token does not seem to exist anywhere in my responses. Nothing in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/nearby-search#about_response) mentions it, and my responses are never more than the list of place results.

I can't find anything online that doesn't just reference the old implementation, and am starting to wonder if they just removed the feature altogether.

If anyone knows the answer let me know! Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/migrate-nearby

Answer (score 0):

Based on the migration guide MrUpsidown commented above, it seems like the pagination feature has been removed in the new version of the API.